# Separable Extension and Splitting Field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Is every Separable extension a splitting field?

Does there exist a counterexample?

Also, is there an algebraically closed extension that is not separable?

Answer (score 5):

$Q(2^{1/3})$ is separable since it is an extension of a field of characteristic zero, but is not a splitting field, since it does not contain complex roots of $X^3-2$.

If a field is not perfect, its algebraic closure is not separable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure#Separable_closure

Comment: Is every separable extension algebraic though?

Comment: @Elliot again just take an extension over a perfect field (e.g. a field of characteristic $0$ or a finite field). For example, $\mathbb Q(\pi)$.